# How to execute one program's output in some different terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell, wxpython

My last question was also same thing, but did not get proper suggestion, so I am asking again.

I have a GUI which will connect to ssh. After it connects to ssh I am not able to do anything , so I have to open new terminal through script do rest of the operation (display respective outputs ) in that 'new terminal'.

Now I am able to open new window using subprocess but its not taking any action from GUI may be code issue. Please help me solve my problem.

I am using python and shell script for the backend and wxpython for GUI.

Note: I'm looking for solutions using Python and shell script.

My code is:

```
import time
import sys
import pexpect
c = pexpect.spawn("ssh -Y -L xxxx:localhost:xxxx user @ host.com")
time.sleep(0.1)
c.expect("[pP]aasword")
c.sendline("xxxxxx")
sub = subprocess.call("xfce4-terminal")
if sub:
   subprocess.call("svn update",shell=True)
time.sleep(0.2)
c.interact()
c.pexpect([user@host.com~]$)
# here after its connects to ssh then command wont be executed
c.sendline("xfce4-terminal")
```

In GUI I have a button "APPLY" and 5 radio button . I can select 1 radio button at a time and have to click button "APPLY". then it have connect to ssh tunnel and do the requested operation . Right now it is not allowing to do any of operation after it gets connect to ssh_tunnel.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: You're not supposed to repeat questions when you're dissatisfied with the answers you got the first time around. Instead, explain in the first question what it is about the answer that falls short of your needs.

Comment: It seems like a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what do you want to happen from a GUI user point of view?

Comment: @JosefAssad:ya i know.. In first question I've asked how to open new terminal window? here its something different.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: connect to ssh tunnel and do svn update, svn log ,build the system and debian file creation .

Comment: @nammu: don't put it in the comments, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16191120/edit) instead. Is the action sequence triggered from the GUI? Do you want to display the progress in the GUI?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian:  Yes ..But facing problem after connecting to ssh_tunnel. it will not take any actions from GUI.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: how to update question?

Comment: edit button under the tags (bottom of your question left side)

Comment: @nammu: click on the link in my previous comment or the [edit] button under the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem that you are seeing is how to avoid blocking the GUI event loop while you are running `ssh`.

There are two major approaches that allow to solve it:

- run `ssh` in a background thread and use [an appropriate for your GUI framework method of communicating with the main GUI thread](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) to report results.
- run `ssh` asynchronously and subscribe to its I/O events. Here's [an example for gtk framework](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63).

To run commands via `ssh`, you could try to use [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org) as a [library](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/library.html) (it is higher level than `paramiko`).